# Unloading resources before Activity finish() in AndEngine

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I've used `System.exit(0)` before to quit my game. But as this is a no-no in Android I tried calling just `activity.finish()`. Now if I start the game again right after quitting it, all textures are messed up (white, stretched, or otherwise messed up).

I'm using both managed and unmanaged textures in AndEngine. And AndEngine version 1 (so no OpenGL ES 2.0).

What are all the unloading I should do manually before quitting the game to avoid this from happening? What do normally unload with OpenGL based Android games? Any tips and tricks are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a really old question. But my problem really was that I had static references to (actually Scala `object`s) that would hold on to the textures even after finishing the activity and only killing the process would help. Really bad design. Be careful with your references on Android.